# My php script won't open files that aren't in its root directory

Tags: php

1. This is a php script for a user login system that I am developing.
2. I need it to read from, and write to, the /students/students.txt file, but it won't even read the content already contained in the file.

---

```
<?php
//other code
echo "...";
setcookie("Student", $SID, time()+43200, "/");
fopen("/students/students.txt", "r");
$content = fread("/students/students.txt", filesize("/students/students.txt"));
echo $content;
fclose("/students/students.txt");
fopen("/students/students.txt", "w");
fwrite("/students/students.txt", $content."\n".$SID);
fclose("/students/students.txt");
//other code
?>
```

Comment: try either a full system path or relative path. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php also and check for permissions.

Comment: Even if I use just "students/students.txt", the same thing happens.

Comment: RTM on `fopen()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php and again; check for errors and folder/file permissions.

Comment: And the website is remotely hosted through Microsoft Azure

Comment: `students/students.txt` is NOT even close to `/students/students.txt`

Comment: get into a habit of using and understanding the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` value, so your file path for file system commands is (for example fopen here: ) `fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/students/students.txt","r")`.

Comment: @Marcin: It's _one_ character different.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No. It's THE one character different.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the former is a relative path. the latter is a fixed path. While the difference in number of characters is small, the actual difference is very big. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths

Comment: @jveazey: Oh thanks I didn't know

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `fopen()` properly. The function returns a handle that you then use to read or edit the file, for example:

```
//reading a file
if ($handle = fopen("/students/students.txt", "r"))
{
    echo "info obtained:<br>";
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle))!==false)
    { echo $buffer;}
    fclose($handle);
}

//writing/overwriting a file
if ($handle = fopen("/students/students.txt", "w"))
{
    fwrite($handle, "hello/n");
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

*P.S.: Ty to the commentators for the constructive feedback.*

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski ? I don't follow, please elaborate. If I'm mistaken somewhere I would love to be educated and know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @Webeng I would say he is referring to the if you could find there : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php#refsect1-function.fgets-examples

Comment: @b.enoit.be ty for the info bro, my answer has been updated

Comment: @Webeng good. I revoked my downvote. BTW you can make it shorter though: `if ($handle = fopen("/students/students.txt", "w")) { ....` will do

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski nice one dude, looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: @Webeng you may shorten it even more: `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` may be good replacements

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I agree, though I prefer to keep `fopen()` here since the users question was asking why his code wasn't working, which happened to be using `fopen()`, though `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` are good replacements.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to read/write to file as others have demonstrated. I just want to illustrate the mistake in your particular approach.

`fread` takes a file handle as param, NOT a string that represents the path to the file.

So your line:

`$content = fread("/students/students.txt", filesize("/students/students.txt"));` is incorrect.

It should be:

```
$file_handle = fopen("/students/students.txt", "r");
$content = fread($file_handle, filesize("/students/students.txt"));
```

Same thing when you write contents to file using `fwrite`. Its reference to the file is a `File Handle` opened using `fopen` NOT the filepath. when opening a file using `fopen()` you can also check if the $file_handle returned is a valid resource or is false. If false, it means the fopen operation was not successful.

So your code:

```
fopen("/students/students.txt", "w");
fwrite("/students/students.txt", $content."\n".$SID);
fclose("/students/students.txt");
```

Needs to be re-written as:

```
$file_handle = fopen("/students/students.txt", "w");
fwrite($file_handle, $content."\n".$SID);
fclose($file_handle);
```

You can see that `fclose` operates on file handles as well.

File Handle (as per php.net):

```
 A file system pointer resource that is typically created using fopen().
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you should probably check if the handle was successfully returned `if ($file_handle){...}` Other than that, looks good. Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php#refsect1-function.fgets-examples

Comment: @Webeng: true, let me add that as well.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue!

Comment: @ChaseStull If this fixed it, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of diagnostic functions that allow you to validate that a file exists and is readable. If it is a permission issue, it gives you the name of the user that needs permission.

```
function PrintMessage($text, $success = true)
{
    print "$text";
    if ($success)
        print "&nbsp;[<font color=\"green\">Success</font>]<br />\n";
    else
        print("&nbsp;[<font color=\"red\">Failure</font>]<br />\n");
}
function CheckReadable($filename)
{
    if (realpath($filename) != "")
        $filename = realpath($filename);
    if (!file_exists($filename))
    {
        PrintMessage("'$filename' is missing or inaccessible by '" . get_current_user() . "'", false);
        return false;
    }
    elseif (!is_readable($filename))
    {
        PrintMessage("'$filename' found but is not readable by '" . get_current_user() . "'", false);
        return false;
    }
    else
        PrintMessage("'$filename' found and is readable by '" . get_current_user() . "'", true);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written your code with (IMO) a cleaner and more efficient code:

```
<?php
$SID = "SOMETHING MYSTERIOUS";
setcookie("Student", $SID, time()+43200, "/");
$file = "/students/students.txt"; //is the full path correct?
$content = file_get_contents($file); //$content now contains /students/students.txt
$size = filesize($file); //do you still need this ?
echo $content;
file_put_contents($file, "\n".$SID, FILE_APPEND); //do you have write permissions ?
```

---

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> `file_get_contents()` **is the preferred way to read the contents of a
>   file into a string**. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported
>   by your OS to enhance performance.

---

[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

> This function is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and
>   `fclose()` successively to write data to a file. If filename does not
>   exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is
>   overwritten, unless the `FILE_APPEND` flag is set.

---

**Notes:**

1. Make **sure** the full path `/students/students.txt` is
   **correct**.
2. Check if you've `read/write` permissions on `/students/students.txt`
3. Learn more about [linux file/folder permissions](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/permissions.php) or, if you don't access to the shell,  [how to change file or directory permissions via ftp](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-to-change-file-or-directory-permissions-via-ftp/)

Comment: It may be worth noting that the full path should probably be appended with the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` value. Otherwise good answer :-)

Comment: Okay but you didn't actually answer the question. You didn't explain what the OP did wrong. You just gave them a different solution for free out of the box.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I partially agree with you, but on my notes I give 3 options that may solve OP's problems

Answer (score -1):

Try to do this:

```
 fopen("students/students.txt", "r");
```

And check to permissions read the file.

Comment: Ummm they already have. Read the comments up there before posting an answer. As stated: *"Even if I use just "students/students.txt", the same thing happens. – Chase Stull 5 mins ago"*

Comment: *"And check to permissions read the file."* - Yeah, [*I said that... didn't I?...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092560/my-php-script-wont-open-files-that-arent-in-its-root-directory#comment61728781_37092560) [twice even.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092560/my-php-script-wont-open-files-that-arent-in-its-root-directory#comment61728861_37092560) *sigh*